# How to run the script in a thread?

Tags: shell, ubuntu-14.04, gnuplot

I am using the bellow script to visualize my result. It will read my `my_model.log` every 10 ms and show in the graph. I save the bellow script as `visualize.sh`

```
refresh_log() {
  while true; do
    python parse_log.py ./my_model.log .
    sleep 10
  done
}
refresh_log &
sleep 2
gnuplot -persist ./gnuplot_commands.py
```

where `gnuplot_commands.py` is

```
# gnuplot_commands
set datafile separator ','
plot 'my_model.log.train' using 1:4  with line title 'training loss'
pause 1
reread
```

My problem is that when I ran the `visualize.sh` from my terminal in Ubuntu. The OS often focus in graph and I cannot do anything. I guess the code is running in main thread. How could I solve it? Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with Python? Despite the `.py` file extension, that file contains gnuplot commands, not Python code.

Comment: Sorry. I removed it

Comment: @Thomas: How about using Process in python? I find a sample code at line 159 https://github.com/faustomilletari/VNet/blob/master/VNet.py